# Polar radius and position vector: two-dimensional kinematics for high school students

Tags: kinematics, definition

We consider for example this image,

[image]
which is a *polar graph* of a naval unit's on-board instrumentation with **vector radius** (or polar radius) $\rho$ and anomaly $\theta$ or **polar angle**.

We know that a point $P=(x,y)$ in an orthogonal Cartesian coordinate system may be identified in a polar diagram with coordinates $P\equiv(\rho,\theta)$ or viceversa.

[image]

> If we consider the trajectory $\Gamma$ (the curve coloured in brown) of a target and $\mathbf r=\mathbf r(t)$ is your **position vector** is it possible to say that there is an analogy between the **position vector** $\mathbf r$ and the **polar radius** $\rho$? Or are the two quantities distinct because the first is a vector and the polar radius is a scalar?

Comment: The polar radius $\rho = |\mathbf r|$.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Yes I agree with you. Thank you very much and all the best.

Comment: @downvoter: Your downvoters an unuseful. Can you put a critique for my question? For me it is a question of polite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position vector $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ is the parametrization of the curve it rides on. But converting this to a polar form $\rho(\theta)$ is also a parameterization of the same curve.

For example an ellipse can be parameteized with

$$ \boldsymbol{r}(t) = \pmatrix{x(t) \\ y(t)} = \pmatrix{ a \cos t \\ b \sin t}  \tag{1}$$

This position vector objeys the equation of the ellipse $$ \left( \tfrac{x}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \tfrac{y}{b} \right)^2 = 1$$ where $a$ is the semi-major axis, and $b$ the semi-minor axis.

Now consider the polar coordinates

$$ \boldsymbol{r}(t) = \pmatrix{x(t) \\ y(t)} = \pmatrix{ \rho \cos \theta \\ \rho \sin \theta} $$

that yields the solution

$$ \rho(\theta) = \frac{ a b}{\sqrt{ a^2 - (a^2-b^2) \cos^2 \theta}} \tag{2}$$

Expressions (1) and (2) are equivalent to each other since both describe the same ellipse.

Comment: THank you very very much. I appreciated always the answer when they are very nice. But when you write $x(t)=\rho \cos \theta$ (for example) is it $\rho\equiv\rho(\theta)$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Sebastiano - you are correct, I just omitted the $(\theta)$ for brevity.

Comment: Ah don't absolutely worry with me. :-) It is a pleasure for me. Why do you write that position vector objeys the equation of the ellipse?

Comment: Plug-in $x$ and $y$ in the equation of the ellipse and it will always be true as it simplifies to $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$.

Comment: Yes, yes....I have understood...$\infty$ grazieeeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

The polar radius is a *scalar* quantity telling you how far you are from the origin.

The position vector is a *vector* hence has *two* pieces of information, magnitude (the polar radius) and direction (the angle). Since you are in 2D, you need two coordinates to unequivocally determine your position: you need the vector.

Comment: Thank thank you always for contribute hoping that often you see also my question :-) My best regards.